# tsconfig.json - add filesGlob entries for directories above tsconfig file

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I am trying to use Typescript to create CasperJS front end tests on an existing Zend Framework 2 project.

ZF2 project structure is setup like this:

```
project
- .composer
- config
- data 
- module
-- Application
-- Module1
--- config (module1 config)
--- src (php sources)
--- view (module1 view files)
--- test
---- Module1Test (has PHPUnit tests)
---- UI
----- Tests
------ SubArea
------ testArea.casper.ts
-- Module2
 ...
- public
- vendor
- tests
-- backend
-- frontend
--- casperjs
...
---- tsconfig.json
```

I am trying to get my tsconfig.json to find and compile all the *.casper.ts files inside each of the apps modules Test directory and into a temporary directory inside the root/tests/frontend. There are about 30 modules.

Currently my file looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./_tmp/build/"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "../../../module/**/test/UI/Tests/Demo/*.casper.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

But it is not finding any files.

How can I make a filesGlob rule for finding files in directories above the tsconfig.json file itself?
Just like :

```
"../../../module/**/test/UI/Tests/Demo/*.casper.ts"
```

Thank you

Comment: What's stopping you from putting your build related files (`tsconfig`, `tslint`, `package.json`, `node_modules`) at the root of your project? That's where they logically belong, especially if you have `.ts` files not under your "frontend root".

Comment: The root project is a ZF2 project and not a ts/js/casper project.

This stuff will be used for testing only at the moment. We have other stuff going on too, if everything is at the root, it becomes wild west.

Comment: +1 for putting tsconfig in the root of your project directory, your file patterns in your filesGlob look like the wild west, jumping around directories and such :). It will also simplify things for you. You should also probably be looking for [long-ass-path]/**/*.casper.ts which will pick up your casper.ts files in any subdirectory of the Demo folder.

Comment: Also, if the folder structure of your project ever changes, the literal path you're using is going to be a nightmare to maintain. I'd recommend simply replacing that whole `../../../blah/blah/blah/blah` path to simply `../../../**/*.casper.ts` - and again, moving tsconfig to the project root, your path will be simplified to just `**/*.casper.ts`

Answer (score 4):

The `filesGlob` is [deprecated](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/334) with the introduction of `include` in the `tsconfig.json` since Typescript 2.0.

The paths specified in the `include` support the glob patterns.

Also, use the broader path for `casper.ts` file with double asterisks as shown in the following format:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
 ...
},
"include": ["./**/casper.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Almost 4 years too late :D

Comment: @JoaoCarlos Haha, yes, better late than never though. Hopefully, it will help other people landing here with the same problem.